# Error in my Recyclerview load infinite

Tags: java, android

i try to build an app using recyclerview and retrofit, but when load the data from JSON file, my recyclerview  it's repeat infinit once the same result.

For sample load all data available, and  after repeat infinitely the results, this way:

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGji9.png)

Normal:

```
--------------------
|      Name 1      |
--------------------
|      Name 2      |
--------------------
|      Name 3      |
--------------------
```

And error

```
--------------------
|      Name 1      |
--------------------
|      Name 2      |
--------------------
|      Name 3      |
--------------------
|      Name 1      |
--------------------
|      Name 2      |
--------------------
|      Name 3      |
--------------------
...
```

Below attach `onScrollListener.java`

```
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager;

public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private int visibleThreshold = 5;

    private int currentPage = 0;

    private int previousTotalItemCount = 0;

    private boolean loading = true;

    private int startingPageIndex = 0;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(GridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager) {
        this.mLayoutManager = layoutManager;
        visibleThreshold = visibleThreshold * layoutManager.getSpanCount();
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
            else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }


    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView view, int dx, int dy) {
        int lastVisibleItemPosition = 0;
        int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();

        if (mLayoutManager instanceof StaggeredGridLayoutManager) {
            int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = ((StaggeredGridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
            // get maximum element within the list
            lastVisibleItemPosition = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof GridLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((GridLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        } else if (mLayoutManager instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {
            lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        if (totalItemCount < previousTotalItemCount) {
            this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
            this.previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
            if (totalItemCount == 0) {
                this.loading = true;
            }
        }

        if (loading && (totalItemCount > previousTotalItemCount)) {
            loading = false;
            previousTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
        }

        if (!loading && (lastVisibleItemPosition + visibleThreshold) > totalItemCount) {
            currentPage++;
            onLoadMore(currentPage, totalItemCount, view);
            loading = true;
        }
    }


    public void resetState() {
        this.currentPage = this.startingPageIndex;
        this.previousTotalItemCount = 0;
        this.loading = true;
    }

    // Defines the process for actually loading more data based on page
    public abstract void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view);

}
```

This is my code in MainActivity into `OnCreate`

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                getInbox();
            }
        });
```

Below load data and build message list `getInbox` into **MainActivity**

```
private void getInbox() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    Map<String, String> datos = new HashMap<>();
    datos.put("ruta", user.getRuta());
    datos.put("jornada", user.getJornada());
    datos.put("id_ppl", user.getId_ppl());
    datos.put("placa", user.getPlaca());
    //datos.put("page", String.valueOf(index));

    Call<List<Message>> call = apiService.getInbox(datos)  ;

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call,  retrofit2.Response<List<Message>> response) {

            // TODO - avoid looping
            for ( Message message : response.body()) {
                // generate a random color
                message.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                messages.add(message);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Message>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch json: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

}
```

This is my `adapter.java`

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private MessageAdapterListener listener;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    // array used to perform multiple animation at once
    private SparseBooleanArray animationItemsIndex;
    private boolean reverseAllAnimations = false;

    // index is used to animate only the selected row
    // dirty fix, find a better solution
    private static int currentSelectedIndex = -1;



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
        public TextView from, subject, message, iconText, timestamp;
        public ImageView iconImp, imgProfile;
        public LinearLayout messageContainer;
        public RelativeLayout iconContainer, iconBack, iconFront;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            from = view.findViewById(R.id.from);
            subject = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_primary);
            message = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_secondary);
            iconText = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            timestamp = view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            iconBack = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_back);
            iconFront = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_front);
            iconImp = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_star);
            imgProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_profile);
            messageContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.message_container);
            iconContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            listener.onRowLongClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
            return true;
        }
    }


    public MessagesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Message> messages, MessageAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.listener = listener;
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        animationItemsIndex = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
         View itemView;

         itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        Message message = messages.get(position);

        // displaying text view data
        holder.from.setText(message.getFrom());
        holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.message.setText(message.getMessage());
        holder.timestamp.setText(message.getTimestamp());

        // displaying the first letter of From in icon text
        holder.iconText.setText(message.getFrom().substring(0, 1));

        // change the row state to activated
        holder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));

        // change the font style depending on message read status
        applyReadStatus(holder, message);

        // handle message star
        applyImportant(holder, message);

        // handle icon animation
        applyIconAnimation(holder, position);

        // display profile image
        applyProfilePicture(holder, message);

        // apply click events
        applyClickEvents(holder, position);




    }

    private void applyClickEvents(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.iconContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onIconClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.iconImp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onIconImportantClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.messageContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onMessageRowClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.messageContainer.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                listener.onRowLongClicked(position);
                view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void applyProfilePicture(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(message.getPicture())) {
            Glide.with(mContext).load(message.getPicture())
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                   // .crossFade()
                   // .transform(new CircleTransform(mContext))
                    //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(holder.imgProfile);
            holder.imgProfile.setColorFilter(null);
            holder.iconText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle);
            holder.imgProfile.setColorFilter(message.getColor());
            holder.iconText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void applyIconAnimation(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
            holder.iconFront.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resetIconYAxis(holder.iconBack);
            holder.iconBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iconBack.setAlpha(1);
            if (currentSelectedIndex == position) {
                FlipAnimator.flipView(mContext, holder.iconBack, holder.iconFront, true);
                resetCurrentIndex();
            }
        } else {
            holder.iconBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resetIconYAxis(holder.iconFront);
            holder.iconFront.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iconFront.setAlpha(1);
            if ((reverseAllAnimations && animationItemsIndex.get(position, false)) || currentSelectedIndex == position) {
                FlipAnimator.flipView(mContext, holder.iconBack, holder.iconFront, false);
                resetCurrentIndex();
            }
        }
    }


    // As the views will be reused, sometimes the icon appears as
    // flipped because older view is reused. Reset the Y-axis to 0
    private void resetIconYAxis(View view) {
        if (view.getRotationY() != 0) {
            view.setRotationY(0);
        }
    }

    public void resetAnimationIndex() {
        reverseAllAnimations = false;
        animationItemsIndex.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return messages.get(position).getId();



    }

    private void applyImportant(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
        if (message.isImportant()) {
            holder.iconImp.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp));
            holder.iconImp.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.icon_tint_selected));
        } else {
            holder.iconImp.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp));
            holder.iconImp.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.icon_tint_normal));
        }
    }

    private void applyReadStatus(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
        if (message.isRead()) {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.message));
        } else {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.from));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        currentSelectedIndex = pos;
        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            animationItemsIndex.put(pos, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public void clearSelections() {
        reverseAllAnimations = true;
        selectedItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selectedItems.size();
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
        List<Integer> items =
                new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public void removeData(int position) {
        messages.remove(position);
        resetCurrentIndex();
    }

    private void resetCurrentIndex() {
        currentSelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    public interface MessageAdapterListener {
        void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle);

        void onProviderEnabled(String s);

        void onProviderDisabled(String s);

        void onIconClicked(int position);

        void onIconImportantClicked(int position);

        void onMessageRowClicked(int position);

        void onRowLongClicked(int position);
    }
```

My PHP file for build Json

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parts = parse_url($url);
$flag = 0;
$page = 1;
if(!empty($_GET)){
    parse_str($parts['query'],$query);
    $page = $query['page'];
    if($page > 1){
        $flag = 1;
    }else{
        $flag = 0;
    }
}
$per_page = 5;
if($flag == 0){
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM registros_not WHERE ruta = '$ruta' AND jornada = '$jornada' AND placa='$placa' AND (id_ppl = '$id_ppl' OR id_ppl = '') ORDER BY fecha_r DESC LIMIT {$per_page}";
}else{
    $page = $page - 1;
    $offset_page = $per_page * $page;
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM registros_not WHERE ruta = '$ruta' AND jornada = '$jornada' AND placa='$placa' AND (id_ppl = '$id_ppl' OR id_ppl = '') ORDER BY fecha_r DESC LIMIT {$per_page} OFFSET {$offset_page}";
}
$res = mysqli_query($con,$qry);
$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($response,array('id'=>$row['idr'],'subject'=>$row['fecha_r'],'isImportant'=>$row['impor_mj'],'from'=>$row['titulo'],'message'=>$row['msj'],'timestamp'=>$row['cel'],'picture'=>$row['picture'],'isRead'=>$row['read_mj']));
}

echo stripslashes(json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

I'm student and still im noob, thnks for any help.

Comment: I think that everytime you scroll, you are calling the method `getInbox()` and that makes the API call execute, so the code you have inside there, just creates the data and adds it to the recycler every time you scroll.

Comment: If that happens, every time I slide, return and load the data, the idea is that it only shows me x number of data, and when I scroll it shows other x number of data, but I could not do it

Comment: Could you show the code from the activity or where you are creating the Recycler's adapter? Anyway, if you want that, you should register or save the position or the amount of data already downloaded or added, so you dont download/add the same data over and over.

Comment: Yes i attach adapter.java

Comment: Its useful, but i meant the code inside your Activity, of how are you creating the adapter, something like: `MessagesAdapter adapter = new MessagesAdapter(..)`

Comment: Into onCreate this: `mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages, this);`

Comment: And `messages` is?

Comment: is this:  `private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you are scrolling, the method `getInbox()` is executed.
Which means that the call to the API is made. 
So inside the `onResponse()` method the data is added to your existing array for the first time, and then it is displayed in: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` Then when you scroll, this is executed again, and the data that arrives, is added to your existing List of Messages here `messages.add(message);` and then, it is displayed (all the data you have now which is the existing items, + the new ones) here again: `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

To check it you can make a simple test, change your `onResponse()` method for this:

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(Call<List<Message>> call,  retrofit2.Response<List<Message>> response) {
            messages.clear;
            // TODO - avoid looping
            for ( Message message : response.body()) {
                // generate a random color
                message.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                messages.add(message);
            }

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

It should just display the data you download, everytime you scroll, so you know you were adding the same data all the time.

In order to implement loading extra different data, every time you scroll, you should ask  your api for "parts" or pages of your data. Not all the data.

Comment: :( not work, i dont know that i do bad, i atcch image

Comment: Te hablo en español xD. ¿A que te refieres?

Comment: jajaja y yo coplicandome en ingles, no no ya si me dio gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: Encantado de ayudar